# Problem from McConnell's book on tensors

Tags: linear-algebra

I got stuck on problem 10.4 on page 17 of Chapter I in McConnell's "Applications of Tensor Analysis":

> If $a_{rs}$ and $b_{rs}$ are both symmetric systems, such that $$a_{rs}b_{tu}-a_{ru}b_{st}+a_{st}b_{ru}-a_{tu}b_{rs}=0$$ then prove that $a_{rs}=k \times b_{rs}$

One approach I've tried is substituting $a_{rs}=a'_{rs}+k\times b_{rs}$ into the given equation; the coefficients of $k$ cancel out, leaving the original equation with all $a_{mn}$ replaced by $a'_{mn}$. Any specific value of $a'_{mn}$ can be zeroed by picking $k=\frac{a_{mn}}{b_{mn}}$. The result could be proved by showing that all values vanish together, but I'm not sure how to go about proving this from here.